# Animating a div with requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, animation

I am trying to animate a `div` horizontally first and then vertically. But the problem using `requestAnimationFrame` is that it is doing both animations at once, making the `div` travel diagonally.

Here is the fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/akonchady/z4qmkuyc/22/

What am I doing wrong?

Note: It works as expected if I give a timeout for the second invocation as follows:

```js
animate('abc', 'marginLeft', 250, 1000);
setTimeout(function() {
  animate('abc', 'marginTop', 250, 1000);
}, 3000);
```

However I want to avoid the timeout. How can I achieve this just using `requestAnimationFrame`?

Comment: Calling `animate` function twice will not help.. Invoke it once and you must have a condition to test the position of the `element`.. And to be frank, `+new Date` will not help as far as _readability_ is concerned...

Comment: @Rayon It does work as expected if I give a timeout for the second invocation of `animate`.

Comment: I am not sure how could you maintain relation between time and distance...

Comment: @Rayon Please see the updated question for the version that works (using `setTimeout`). But that isn't what I want.

Comment: You will have to introduce `setTimeout` if you are invoking 2 different function where you want second function to do something after certain duration...

Comment: I need the second function to execute after 1st function is executed, in the same order. I don't see why I need to use `setTimeout` for the normal flow of function execution. Shouldn't there be a better way !

Comment: _Yes,_ Second function is executed right after first one is executed.. Why would second function wait for the first function.. Statements are executed serially....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Most `functions` in JavaScript are synchronous(will execute sequentially). But with `asynchronous` functions(which will not wait for earlier function to finish), use `callbacks` to control the flow of the execution.

To invoke send `function` when first one is done with the animation, use `callback`

```js
function animate(id, styleAttr, finalValue, duration, callback) {
  var ele = document.getElementById('abc'),
    startTime = +new Date, //Not sure how readable this is ?
    delta = null,
    req = null;

  (function timeout() {
    elapsedTime = +new Date - startTime;
    if (elapsedTime >= duration) {
      cancelAnimationFrame(req);
      ele.style[styleAttr] = finalValue + 'px';
      if (typeof callback !== 'undefined') {
        callback();
      }
      return;
    } else {
      delta = finalValue / duration;
      ele.style[styleAttr] = delta * elapsedTime + 'px';
    }
    req = requestAnimationFrame(timeout);
  })();
}
animate('abc', 'marginLeft', 250, 1000, function() {
  animate('abc', 'marginTop', 250, 1000);
});
```

```css
#abc {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id='abc'>
</div>
```

### [**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/z4qmkuyc/23/)